# Formula to calculate chances (poker probability)

Tags: excel, probability, worksheet-function, factorial, poker

The chance to have any 5 cards in poker is C(52,5) = 52! / [5!(52-5)!], so it is any 5 cards from all 52 possible cards. I tried using =prob(52,5,1,52) function, but I have no idea how to write it to get the correct outcome of 2598960.

I was wondering whether I can use a simple function to calculate that instead of long FACT() function.Should I use this function? How? If not this one, how should I do this correctly to get the right number?

Comment: You have the math right there, have you tried writing a factorial fuction?  It's a fun example of basic recursion.

Comment: "prob(52,5,1,52)" in which language?

Comment: What language are you talking about? Anyway, C(52,5) won't give you the probability to draw those 5 cards. Probability is always between 0 and 1. That number represents the number of possible draws that are different, not keeping into account different orders.

Comment: Apologies, of course probability is between 0 and 1. I want to calculate chances...

I'm doing this directly in Excel, not in VBA macro or something else.

Comment: Yes, COMBIN works, Thanks!!!:)

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering whether I can use a simple function to calculate that instead of long FACT() function.

Yes, please try [COMBIN](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/combin.php), for example:

```
=COMBIN(52,5)
```